# Export "Project from view" texture as uv texture

Tags: modeling, export

I've created texture for my model using the "project from view" and edited it externally. However, to use it, it needs to be exported from blender as a uv map (with the colors on)

As suggested I've added a picture trying to describe what I'm looking for. This is the best way I can put it. (UV map in bottom right is what I'm looking for. Where the texture from the gun would be pinned down on a UV map to match the UV map. This is for CS:GO where the guns need the texture to be painted on the UV map)

[image]

Comment: There is such menu in UV/Image Editor: UVs > Export UV Layout. However the colors won't be on, only map.

Comment: I think this needs more clarification about what you have and what you are trying to achieve. Maybe some screenshots would help.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, it sounds like you are trying to remap your texture. You may find this helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4ngVoGIj1Q

Answer (score 1):

You can Bake the texture onto your UV map.

1. with your model selected in the 3d View, open the Uv/Image Editor and create a new image. Name it and dimension it however you like. Otherwise you can just leave the image blank for now.
2. With your model still selected in the 3d View, open the Node Editor. You don't need to mess with the material at all. Just add an Image Texture node using the blank image you just created. **Make sure the Image Texture node is selected**. It should have a brighter border than notes that aren't selected.
3. In the **Render Panel** of the Properties Editor, scroll down to the Bake section. The default Bake Type is Combined. If you just want the diffuse portion of the material, select **Diffuse Color** from the dropdown list.
4. Click **Bake** and the texture should appear in UV Editor aligned with your model's UV map.

[image: Baked Texture]

Pink stripes mapped to original material with a separate 'Projected from View' UV map. Return to step one to bake as one texture map. Just be sure to have the original UV selected as active in the Properties Editor when doing so.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I only have "Material" and "Output" in my node editor. When pressing add>search>image texture nothing comes up. Here's a link to a picture showing my screen as I can't attach it to the message. http://gyazo.com/cfabe64ab804e0eecc441d4fd7176704

Comment: Ok so it looks like you are using "Blender Render" as your rendering engine. I'm sorry I just assumed you were using "Cycles Render". At the top of the screen it says one or the other. You can switch it by clicking on the text. Before you do that could save a copy of the image named Untitled.001. Then see if you can follow the steps I listed. If you have any trouble, I'm happy to help. Please just post a link to a screenshot of the Untitled.001 image so I can see how it is mapped to your gun.

Comment: Just to be sure that we are talking about the same thing - http://gyazo.com/4947ea600a9395d366e0fa22daccb2af . Whenever I create a new UV map, the old UV "Project from View" still shows up. Upon baking the image texture I recieve a update in the UV map that creates a black layer enlarged layer of project from view.

Comment: I think what's happening here is that when you unwrapped your model using 'Project from View', you replaced the original UV map that came with the .obj file. I feel like I might have misunderstood and I don't want to lead you down the wrong path. We may be talking about two separate issues here. Would it be possible to link the blend file or the original obj, or give me the link to the site you downloaded it from? Otherwise I don't really know how to explain what I'm talking about.

Comment: Google Drive link with all project files - https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzZPcMb-htyNfkc1RWtmU1JKcHNnbUFfOTlNNTJzVEJtT2xFMnRYOG1faEFRS3kzVmpjVXc&usp=sharing . I also found a video showing what I'm looking for, in another program unfortunately. I don't know if it helps, but you can always have a look - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FiNASmArkxA

Comment: Cool. I'll have a look. We kind of drifted outside of my area of "expertise" so that's good you're continuing to research. Hopefully the youtube tutorial pans out but I won't leave you hanging. We'll get it figured out.

Comment: There is just too much to explain so here is the completed blend file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_u_PgL8nJc9RE9nMmlEbmtaaGM/view?usp=sharing  Note that the original UV mapping that was embedded into the obj file is used for the main dark part of the material. Then I added a second UV map using "Projected from view". to add the pink stripes. Notice the two different UV Map inputs in the Node Editor and the the Data tab of the Properties Editor. Also I separated the saturation value from the image to use as a mask. To bake, follow the original instructions I posted.  Happy hunting!

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, but where's the UV map (the original one just with the texture painted on it)? Sorry for requiring to much help :)

Comment: I used the images that you linked in your comment. Drag and drop from your computer to the Image Editor and reconnect them to the Image Texture nodes.

Comment: Okay, my bad. Poorly written. Meant where is the UV grid with painting on that I'm looking for. CS:GO requires only the UV map with colors on, and does not accept a 3d model. That's the issue. I need to kind of, probably the wrong term, to unwrap the texture off the model to a UV map as the one that I provided (just with colors of the texture added the corresponding places). This can be done in 3Dcoat and Zbrush, so figured it could be done here also.

Comment: This is what baking accomplishes as I described initially. I'm happy to help with that part but the other questions you are asking are too broad to cover here. You have everything you need within the blend file I sent. Now just follow the steps I listed and bake it. You must focus Danielson!