# Baking error with multi-tiled UV map

Tags: rendering, uv, uv-image-editor

While searching for examples in baking I found this question [Export "Project from view" texture as uv texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33373/export-project-from-view-texture-as-uv-texture) . On that page one responder provided a [blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_u_PgL8nJc9RE9nMmlEbmtaaGM/view?usp=sharing). I downloaded it, tried to follow the steps and encountered a problem.

The model is unwrapped in such a way that it spreads across 4 different tiles: (*I understand why and I also do this in my own projects, so it's a lot easy to manage*)[image]
The problem is: 
 
When I bake the texture on the left to the layout on the right, the resulting texture is just a fraction of the tile (0,0). 
 [image] 

But when I cram those 4 tiles into just 1 tile it bakes correctly: 
 [image]

Even when I tried to **UVs -> Export UV Layout** to use for pics in this question, Blender exported only the tile (0.0). 
 [image] 

How to make Blender respect multi-tiled UV maps and how to make this particular example work (without collapsing all into 1 tile)? 


Notes: 
*renderer used is Cycles* 
*different UV tiles doesn't mean different UV maps* 
*I have no idea where exactly the original asker got that model from*

Comment: Huh... I'd always believed that anything outside the UV tile <1,1> just wouldn't bake/map properly. I have a hard time understanding how something like this would work...

Answer (score -1):

Always layout UVs up and right from 0,0. Otherwise this will happen. Never go left and down.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I for one am having a hard time understanding what you are trying to say.